# What is a tool to test socket connections on Windows which supports TLS

Tags: windows, ssl

I want a TCP/IP client which can connect to a server and send/receive messages but it should support TLS. That is I need to specify the certificate files for the connection. Basically I need something like [Hercules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515328/good-tool-for-testing-socket-connections) but supporting TLS. Do you have any such recommendations?

Comment: Have you consider using `openssl` and command line?

Comment: You can use `socat` to forward all incoming data of a TCP socket to a TLS-TCP socket. Then you could just continue to use Hercules.